# How to maximize the security of the database of my application?

Tags: database, security, mobile, storage

I'm working on a startup with some friends, I will be creating an application that will share a lot of sensitive data among users.

In terms of security, what do I need to worry about, besides buying a very expensive account at a storage server company, and a good developer?
What technologies do I need them to use (for the database)?
Do I need the service of a security expert, or the expensive account at the storage company will do the job?
How much does it cost?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Oh just sql injection, DOS/DDOS attacks, inside leaks, possible man in the middle attacks, a little cross-site scripting, etc, etc, here take a look at the OWASP top 10:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10

Comment: Thanks a lot!  this is a good start. If these 10 "rules" are respected, is it enough? these "rules" are handled by the developer I guess, what about the costs besides (like choice of the server)?

Comment: np.  I don't know how to handle all of them, but I do for a few.  You can completely 100% of the time avoid sql injection if you just use prepared statements. 
For DOS/DDOS attacks, it varies depending on whatever you're developing.  You need a way to recognize honest traffic towards you instead of some guy overloading your server.  For example, a website that lets you add other users might set a limit on how many users you can add per minute.  If you stop a DOS attack on the client side, then that's great because your server can keep moving along with all the other clients without caring.

Comment: Thank you again! I didn't know about that OWAS Project and it's good stuff.